# Display single item in Meteor + Flowrouter + React

Tags: javascript, meteor, flow-router

Am a little bit stuck with Meteor, Flowrouter and React when it comes to display single items. Have been trying several solutions but don't know how to transfer the ID to my React class and can't really find any information. A push in the right direction to help understand how to do this correctly would be very appreciated

My route looks like this

```
FlowRouter.route('/video/:_id', {
    name: "video",
    action(pathParams, queryParams) {
        console.log("Got the postId from the URL:", pathParams._id);
        console.log("Query parameters:", queryParams);
        ReactLayout.render(App, {
            content: <Play />
    });
}
});
```

So this help me get the ID and then in my Play React Class i have this code

```
Play = React.createClass({
  renderPlay() {
    return Videos.findOne(FlowRouter.getParam("_id"));
  }, 
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
      {this.renderPlay()}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

But what i really would like to do is to pass the information to my React Clip class and also put values in variables.

```
Clip = React.createClass({
  getDefaultProps: function () {
    return {
      src : 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/',
      width: 1600,
      height: 900
    }
  },
  propTypes: {
    video: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
  },
  render() {
    return (

      <iframe
      src={this.props.src + this.props.video.videoId} frameBorder={ 0 }>
      </iframe>
    );
  }
});
```

To do this i would need to include something like this in my Play class.

```
  renderVideo() {
    // Get tasks from this.data.tasks
    return this.data.videos.map((video) => {
        return <Clip key={video._id} video={video} />;
    });
  },
```

Would love to understand how to do this correctly and it would really be a big step in the right direction to to understand this stack.

*Tutorials and guides covering Meteor + React + kadira:Flowrouter + kadira:ReactLayout that handle more than just single page apps are welcome.*